# Tf.graph has no attribute 'graph' in mac m1

Tags: python, tensorflow

[Edit-01] A comment told me to run `print(tensorflow.__file__)` and the result is `None`

This is the simplest code in Tensorflow (directly from website)

```
import tensorflow as tf
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
  # Define operations and tensors in `g`.
  c = tf.constant(30.0)
  assert c.graph is g
```

And this is what I am getting

```
% /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/-----/Downloads/eye_contact_gaze_correction-master/gaze_correct
ion_system/things.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/-----/Downloads/eye_contact_gaze_correction-master/gaze_correction_system/things.py", line 2, in <module>
    g = tf.Graph()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Graph'
```

On a side note, when I am trying to do `pip install tensorflow`, it will always show this error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

However, when I do `pip list`,this happened:

```
...
SQLAlchemy                    1.4.32
stack-data                    0.2.0
statsmodels                   0.13.2
sympy                         1.10.1
tables                        3.6.1
tabulate                      0.8.9
TBB                           0.2
tblib                         1.7.0
tenacity                      8.0.1
tensorboard                   2.9.1
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.9.1
tensorflow-estimator          2.9.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.26.0
termcolor                     1.1.0
terminado                     0.13.1
testpath                      0.5.0
text-unidecode                1.3
textdistance                  4.2.1
threadpoolctl                 2.2.0
three-merge                   0.1.1
tifffile                      2021.7.2
tinycss                       0.4
...
```

So apparently tensorflow was installed but it just can't run modules?
I tried many things, such as anaconda, apple's tensorflow-metal, and directly downloading the tensorflow file, but none of those works.

M1 Macbook air

Python 3.10.0

How could I get tf.graph to work?

Comment: The most common cause of this error is that you have added your own file called "tensorflow.py".  Python will pick that one instead of yours.  Do `print(tensorflow.__file__)`.

Answer (score 0):

I could able to resolve the issue with

```
tensorflow-macos        2.9.2
tensorflow-metal        0.5.0
```

Install Tensorflow metal plugin

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```

[image]